# Berkshire Hathaway ticker symbol B

Tags: data, quantmod

I want to read the Berkshire Hathaway data using the getSymbols function in the quantmod package in R.

The ticker symbol is BRK-B.

```
getSymbols ( "BRK-B" )
```

yields the error message:

```
Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "BRKB", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE,  : 
  Unable to import “BRKB”.
HTTP error 404.
```

There is something about that hyphen!

How do I correct things?

Answer (score 3):

What version of the `quantmod` package are you using? With 0.4.23, it works for me:

```
library("quantmod")
getSymbols("BRK-B") 
get("BRK-B") ## or `BRK-B`
##            BRK.B.Open BRK.B.High BRK.B.Low BRK.B.Close BRK.B.Volume BRK.B.Adjusted
## 2007-01-03      73.56      73.72     72.60       72.86      1385000          72.86
## 2007-01-04      72.86      72.94     72.06       72.20      1070000          72.20
## 2007-01-05      72.66      72.66     71.26       71.56       930000          71.56
## ....
```